# Updating location field (geometry) in Oracle Spatial using asp.net web application

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, oracle-spatial, sdo-geometry, spatial-data-infrastructure

I want to update a geometry column in Oracle Spatial database via Asp.net web application, I couldn't find samples for update query or datatypes that can hold geometry data in asp.net.

I use C# for server side , Oracle Spatial 11g ,asp.net web forms and ESRI JsAPI.